# Order the following functions by growth rate and indicate which functions grow at the same rate

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science

The question is

> Order the following functions by growth rate: $N$, $N^{1/2}$, $N^{1.5}$, $N^2$, $N\log N$, $N\log\log N$, $N\log^2N$, $N\log(N^2)$, $2/N$, $2^N$, $2^{N/2}$, $37$, $N^2\log N$, $N^3$. Indicate which functions grow at the same rate.

1. constant/bounded functions
2. logarithmic
3. linear
4. linearithmic
5. polynomial
6. exponential
7. super-exponential

The order from the fastest to the slowest is $2^N, 2^{N/2}, N^3, N^2, N^2\log N, N^{1.5}, N\log^2N, N\log(N^2), N\log N, N\log\log N, N, N^{1/2}, 37, 2/N$

Among these, $N\log(N^2)$ and $N\log N$ grow at the same rate.

Can anyone confirm my answer? I'm not sure if there's anything wrong in how I compare the logarithms and if I miss any functions that grow at the same rate. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, please use text instead of images, as sometimes images may not be displayed properly on certain devices. Also, you can use `> ` (with a space after >) for qutoes

Comment: Ah, my apologies. Only the placement of $\frac{2}{N}$ is incorrect. You can check your work by plugging in large values of $N$, I think $N = 1000$ should already clearly reveal the exact order.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan where should the $\frac{2}{N}$ go?

Comment: Have you tried plugging in any values of $N$ at all? Think about how it grows! Make a graph!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I did. From the graph, it seems like the slope of $\frac{2}{N}$ is getting smaller and smaller as N gets bigger. That's why I think it should be the last one. If we are asked to order growth rate, aren't we supposed to order how FAST they grow?

Comment: The use of "growth rate" in this context is not in the sense of derivative. It's the actual size of the function as $N$ grows without bound. So $2/N$ is below any constant for $N$ large enough. In other words $2/N$ is *little-o* of a constant, or $o(1).$

Comment: @kodlu so $\frac{2}{N}$ should be after 37?

Comment: Yes, it's correct now.